# Google Sheets Custom Date Format as Default

Tags: date, google-sheets, format

I am trying to set a **Custom Default Date Format**  *across* the board. For Example, when I share my *Google Sheets 'Workbook'* to my colleagues, if they enter a **date** in *any* cell (in any *Sheet*), the date should display as **'Sep-30'**. For those familiar with *MS Excel*, there is a **Region and Language** setting with *Short Date*, *Long Date* and other customizations.

I know I could manually select all the cells in each sheet and set the desired date format. But is there a more efficient way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unfortunately Google Sheets does not feature Custom Default Date Format

- It [specifies](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers&visit_id=637371339984263950-1138104041&rd=1):

> By default, the time and date options that surface will be based on your spreadsheet locale.

- So you can adapt your spreadsheet locale according to the formatting you desire, [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106243) you can find a good overview of the formattings for different locale.
- However, I am not aware of a locale that would display the months by default in "mmm" format
- An alternative workaround would be to use [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) where the method [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) would allow you to set all sheets of a desired spreadsheet programmaticaly to the desired format.
- Also, if you go on `Help -> Report a problem` you can ask Google to implement the custom default date format - they might do it in the future.